# Как наложить картинку на блок?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

У меня есть блок и есть картинка. Как наложить одно на другое?

```css
 #box {
     width: 100%;
     height: 150px;
     background-color: #15B575;
     }

    #logo {
     margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

```html
  <header>
      <div id='box'></div>
      <img id='logo' scr='somefoto'>
    </header>
```

Не понимаю как поднять картинку.

Comment: А можете сделать ваш код запускаемым?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
#box {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #15B575;
 }

#logo {
 margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
header {
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id='box'></div>
  <img id='logo' scr='somefoto'>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать отрицательное значение свойства margin-top, например:

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Хотя, судя по названию блоков, правильнее разместить картинку с логотипов внутри контейнера с id box.

Answer (score 4):

Самым простым и наиболее сопроводжаемым решением будет вложить картинку в блок и задать блоку `position: relative;`, а картинке `position: absolute;`.

Далее смещать картинку с помощью CSS-свойств `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` от соответствующей стороны блока в нужных вам единицах измерения.

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;

  /* Просто для демонстрации */
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#logo {
  position: relative;

  /* Просто для демонстрации */
  left: 30px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <img id="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-100-6.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: зачем изображение внутрь box если есть уже обертка header? Зачем box абсолют, если изображение нужно наложить на блок. И это "Самым простым ..."

Comment: @user3178479 Можно изображение не внутри `box`, я просто показал сам принцип. И это действительно самым простым способом. И я бы также больше склонялся к отрицательным `margin` если это подходит.